# What is the easiest way to create a inherited class in Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, class, inheritance

I'm a Qt newbie and all I'm trying to do is create a custom `QLineEdit` class with a few customizations (default alignment and default text). Right now I'm just trying to establish a base class, inheriting only `QWidget`. This is what I have (very bad code I know):

userText (utxt.h):

```
#ifndef UTXT_H
#define UTXT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLineEdit>

class utxt : public QWidget

{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit utxt(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QString text () const;
    const QString displayText;

    Qt::Alignment   alignment;
    void setAlignment(Qt::Alignment);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // UTXT_H
```

utxt.cpp:

```
#include "utxt.h"

utxt::utxt(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QString utxt::text()
    {
        return this->displayText;
    }

    void utxt::setAlignment(Qt::Alignment align)
    {
       this->alignment = align;
    }
}
```

I know this is really wrong, and I keep getting "local function definition is illegal" errors on the two functions in utxt.cpp. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm just trying to create a custom `QLineEdit` to promote my other line edits to.

Comment: Looks like you're a C++ newbie as well.  You can't define functions within a constructor.  You should really start off with simpler projects before trying to work with Qt.  If you want to create "a custom QLineEdit" then inherit from QLineEdit, for starters.

Comment: Oh my God, I'm an idiot! I'm so used to class definitions being in the source file, like in C#, I just assumed it was a class definition. I placed my functions out of the constructor and the errors cleared up. Thanks! One question though... if I inherit from QLineEdit, do I also inherit from QWidget? Because I think I tried inheriting once from just QLineEdit, and functions such as SetGeometry, etc, were not available. Do I have to inherit both?

Comment: No, you can't inherit from both QWidget and QLineEdit (because both inherit indirectly from QObject and you can't have QObject twice in your class hierarchy), anyway tell us more about what are you trying to do, because the functionality you describe can be done without inheriting from QLineEdit.

Answer (score 0):

`QLineEdit` already has the [alignment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#alignment-prop) that can be set and also [placeholderText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop).

LE: As I said there is no need to inherit from `QLineEdit` (or `QWidget`) for this functionality, but if you really want to do it you can just create your class and code a constructor that takes the parameters you want and call `QLineEdit`'s functionality with that, something like:

```
//in the header
//... i skipped the include guards and headers 
class utxt : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
//you can provide default values for all the parameters or hard code it into the calls made from the constructor's definition
    utxt(const QString& defaultText = "test text", Qt::Alignment align = Qt::AlignRight, QWidget *parent = 0);
};

//in the cpp
utxt::utxt(const QString& defaultText, Qt::Alignment alignement, QWidget *parent) :     QLineEdit(parent)
{
//call setPlaceHolder with a parameter or hard-code the default
    setPlaceholderText(defaultText); 
//same with the default alignement
    setAlignment(alignement); 
}
```